# Apigee: Unable to authenticate with Management Server

Tags: apigee

I'm installing Apigee on a single node but when running this command:

```
/opt/apigee/apigee-setup/bin/setup.sh -p aio -f configFile
```

I get this stack error at the end:

```
Checking if management-server is up management-server is up.

Finished edge-management-server setup

Checking for required variables
Checking required variable MSIP...OK
Checking required variable ADMIN_EMAIL...OK

Checking for optional variables
Found optional variable APIGEE_ADMINPW...OK
Found optional variable APIGEE_PORT_HTTP_MS...OK
http://10.10.37.31:8080/v1/servers/self......
Unable to authenticate with Management Server
Error: setup.sh: /opt/apigee/apigee-service/bin/apigee-service exited with unexpected status 1
```

I've already tried with uninstalling and reinstalling but still getting the same error:

```
/opt/apigee/apigee-service/bin/apigee-service apigee-service uninstall
```

This is my configFile:

```
# With SMTP
IP1=10.10.37.31
HOSTIP=$(hostname -i)
ENABLE_SYSTEM_CHECK=y
ADMIN_EMAIL=name.surname@org.ch
# Admin password must be at least 8 characters long and contain one uppercase
# letter, one lowercase letter, and one digit or special character
APIGEE_ADMINPW=Apigeepw2020
LICENSE_FILE=/tmp/license.txt
MSIP=$IP1
LDAP_TYPE=1
APIGEE_LDAPPW=Apigeepw2020
MP_POD=gateway
REGION=dc-1
ZK_HOSTS="$IP1"
ZK_CLIENT_HOSTS="$IP1"
# Must use IP addresses for CASS_HOSTS, not DNS names.
CASS_HOSTS="$IP1"
# Default is postgres
PG_PWD=postgres
SKIP_SMTP=y
SMTPHOST=smtp.example.com
SMTPUSER=smtp@example.com
# omit for no username
SMTPPASSWORD=SMTP_PASSWORD
# omit for no password
SMTPSSL=n
SMTPPORT=25
SMTPMAILFROM="My Company <myco@company.com>"
```